# id's who have particulars years data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding Oracle SQL.

My data looks like this:

```
id   year
--   ----
1    2000
1    2001
1    2002
1    2003
1    2006
1    2000
2    2001
2    2002
2    2003
3    2003
3    2005 
4    2012
4    2013
```

I want the `id`'s which have the years 2001, 2002, 2003.

My result set:

```
id   
--
1
2
```

Please help me with this. I actually tried searching this, but couldn't figure a way to search about my particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQL**

```
SELECT t.id
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.year in(2001,2002,2003)
GROUP BY t.id
```

**Sample SqlFiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ec9f/2/0

**Explanation**

You want to filter your data set to only show rows with certain years, so that is what you put in the where clause `WHERE t.year in(2001,2002,2003)`.

Since a single id can be in multiple years, your result set would contain duplicates. To remove the duplicates you could [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) the ID or use the [DISTINCT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php) statement to only show unique elements.

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, here's a version that will only display id's that have all three years. We use `DISTINCT t.YEAR` to avoid counting id's that perhaps would have a single year repeated multiple times. The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.YEAR) = 3` part ensures that we only include id's that have all three years.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM years t
WHERE t.year in(2001,2002,2003)
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.YEAR) = 3
```

Updated [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40a23/4/0), which includes a data set where id of 3 has two rows for 2003 to show off the logic that only counts unique years for an ID.

Comment: Really should *only* be using `DISTINCT`. And reference the manual, not some 3rd party website.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I tend to stay away from using `DISTINCT` since I've seen people use it all the time without understanding the data that's returned. Often times I've seen it used to remove duplicates because of bad joins. But yes you are correct, in this case `DISTINCT` would have been appropriate. Which site would you recommend? I've used techonthenet often times as a quick reference.

Comment: Hi Jarek, thanks for the reply. This doesn't seem to work for me. Say we have include on more row to my test data. 3(Id)    2003(year)..I don't like 3(id) to be part of my result. I only want Id(s) who have (2001 and 2002 and 2003)

Comment: @avg998877 Why don't you want to see the 3 id if it has the year 2003? Are there other fields that you want to filter the result set by?

Comment: for id-3 we only have years(2003) but not years(2001 and 2002). I want to have ids who have years(2001 and 2002 and 2003) (Note: edited the query with new test data)

Comment: @avg998877 Ok that is a slightly different question than what I interpreted from your origional post. Check out the update.

Comment: Thanks a ton..Jarek..this is the best site with help around all the time

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct id
from table
where year in(2001,2002,2003)
```